# Statsmodels doesn't work even though I installed it

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, statsmodels

I'm having this issue the past couple of days that is preventing me from getting into my project. So, I have installed statmodels and whenever I type "pip list" in the VS Code Terminal I can clearly see that statsmodels 0.12.2 is installed.

My issue is that on the line that I try to import the library.

```py
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
```

This error pops up:

```py
Unable to import 'statsmodels.tsa.seasonal'pylint(import-error)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this are highly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure VS project is using the environment that statsmodels is installed into. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: Oh my god . This makes me feel like a noob . Thanks!